# Font size discrepancy between computed font size and CSS defined font size?

Tags: html, css, font-size

I have a certain HTML element: a textarea with some CSS

```
<textarea id="mytextarea" 
    class="absoluteelement inputtable paddable"
    style="resize:none;top:70.68187%;left:4.705374%;width:90%;height:11.5%;Background-color:transparent;">
</textarea>
```

And the css:

```
#mytextarea {
    font-size: 10.0px;
    font-color: #FF000000;
    font-family: arial;
    text-align: left;
}

input,select,textarea {
    border: none;
    background: transparent;
}

.paddable {
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; /*FF, IE8*/
}

textarea {
    resize: none;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.absoluteelement {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Now my problem is this. When I try

```
var textarea = document.getElementById("mytextarea");
var style = window.getComputedStyle(textarea);
console.log(style.fontSize);
```

The console logs `9.85012722015381px`. Yet when I inspect the textarea with Chrome's developers panel (style tab), it shows

```
#mytextarea {
    font-size: 10.0px;
    font-color: #FF000000;
    font-family: arial;
    text-align: left;
}
```

and in the computed panel, it shows, like the console output:

```
> font-size: 9.85012722015381px;
```

Why is there a discrepancy between the two values? I clearly stated that the font size is 10.0px, and I can't find the number 9.85...px anywhere in my css.

UPDATE:

This does only seem to happen in Chrome; Firefox displays and logs a computed font size of `10.0px`

UPDATE 2:

It seems the fontSize changes when zooming in or out on Chrome.

Comment: IS that all the code, I get an error in firefox on jsbin. does it change if the font size is 10px rather than 10.0px?

Comment: Not reproduceable. The exact code in the question, when combined to form an HTML document, causes the console message “10px” on Chrome  39.0.2171.99 (Win 7).

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I just saw the fontSize change when zooming in and out. Does happen in Chrome, not in FF

Comment: Yes, for some zooming factors, the `fontSize` value seems to differ somewhat from 10px. This is probably just a feature of the implementation of zooming in the browser.

Answer (score -2):

As far as I know, it's really the Chrome-specific issue.

First of all, if you set the font size in pixels, you should use only the round numbers, i.e. `font-size: 10px;` and not `font-size: 10.0px;` The floating-point numbers are meaningless for pixels and only put browser down.

However, you should't worry because all the numbers you provide are actually mapped to 10px font size. If you need to recognize the actual font size in your code in order to do something with it, you can round the number:

```
var myTextArea = document.getElementById("mytextarea");
var fontSize = window.getComputedStyle(myTextArea).fontSize.replace("px","");
var fontSize = Math.round(fontSize);
```

Comment: 10.0px and 10.5px are perfectly valid and meaningful values for `font-size`. Whether browsers round or miscalculate things is a different issue.

Comment: Could you please explain what is the meaning of 9.85px font size or provide a link to an explanation?

Comment: If I create two divs, with respectively 10px and 9.85px fontSize, with the same text, the div widths differ.

Comment: @AlexanderDayan, there is nothing to be defined in addition to the meaning of the `font-size` property in general and the `px` unit in general. These are difficult concepts, but using a non-integer numeric value does not make it any more difficult.

Comment: `Math.round` used on a `DOM` element is not going to return a number.

Comment: And so 10.0px (pay attention, .0!) is better than just 10px? The use of floating point number is certainly meaningful with em, in or similar, but when a developer sets the size in pixels he usually wants it to have an exact size in pixels. Moreover, use of floating point size with pixels may cause the unpredictable behavior of elements like the situation described in the comment of @stealthjong.